# CSS animation loop - next loop should start from the end of the previous one

Tags: css, animation, transition

Let's say I have animation that bring red square from top to the bottom - thing happens say every 5 seconds. Once the square drops to the bottom after 5 seconds, script will teleport our red square back to the top so the loop could start over again from the top. Thing is it doesn't look natural at all.

What I want to achieve is to start second loop smoothly from bottom to the top, then again from top to the bottom etc. so the movement looks natural and smooth. In other words - red square will bounce from top to the bottom every 5 seconds. Any suggestions?

Comment: Single animation loop should have full cycle (top>down, 5s, down>top, 5s). Then you can run it in loop.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Like dummy example of what you just said?

Comment: This site works other way around. Update your question with code you have tried so far ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and somebody may be able to help you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are looking for that.

May be it will help you.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: It's probably 'animation-direction: alternate;' I've been looking for. Thanks a LOT friend!